# zephyr for jira to use same jira test case id to update test results

Tags: jira-zephyr

I have configured zephyr and jenkins using the below article.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Zephyr+For+Jira+Test+Management+Plugin

Currently the tests created by ZAPI are creating new test case ids. Is there a way to pass the original jira test id as part of junit test result and let zapi create/update the same results in JIRA instead of using a new test case id.

Or I can do this using the REST api ? what rest calls do I need to use to 
Create test cycle, add tests to this cycle with the same jira id and update their status

Comment: @shailesh mangal could you please provide me some clues as to how we can parse the junit test result xml and post the execution results in zephyr. what rest calls do I need to use to Create test cycle, add tests to this cycle with the same jira id and update their status